# AngularJS data binding redrawing inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

If i had a scope like this one

```
$scope.array = [ { a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 2, b: 1 }];
```

With a view:

```
<div>A:
  <div ng-repeat="obj in array">{{obj.a}}</div>
</div>
```

Having in mind that the expression {{obj.a}} is served vía the ng-repeat directive, my question is if the AngularJS watcher behind the expression {{obj.a}} will execute if i change obj.b like this

```
$scope.players[0].b = 666
```

In other words, having an array of objects drawn in the screen, if i change an attribute that is not binded to the view of one of those objects, ¿will the view try to redraw itself anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the interpolation is using the [`$parse`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse) service to figure out what to watch on.  It will only update that text node when `obj.a` changes.

It is similar to writing `$scope.$watch("obj.a", handler)`.  In this case, it is evaluating that statement on every digest.  If the result of that statement changes, then it will call your function.  In the case of interpolation, the callback function then updates the DOM.